# Android SQLite insert JSON in TEXT column with escaping double quotes

Tags: android, json, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I am using SQLite in an Android app which stores, amongst other things, a table that records the mood of the user.  The table schema is shown below

```
CREATE TABLE moods
(
 dow INTEGER,
 tsn INTEGER,
 lato INTEGER,
 agitation TEXT DEFAULT '{}',
 preoccupancy TEXT DEFAULT '{}',
 tensity TEXT DEFAULT '{}',
 taps TEXT DEFAULT '{}'     
);
```

Unlike, say, Postgres, SQLite does not have a dedicated `jsonb` storage type.  To quote

> Backwards compatibility constraints mean that SQLite is only able to store values that are NULL, integers, floating-point numbers, text, and BLOBs. It is not possible to add a sixth "JSON" type.

[SQLite JSON1 extension documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html)

On the SQLite commandline processor I can populate this table using a simple INSERT statement such as this one

```
INSERT INTO moods (dow,tsn,lato,agitation,preoccupancy,tensity,taps) 
VALUES(1,0,20,'{"A2":1}','{"P4":2}','{"T4":3}','{"M10":4}');
```

since it accepts both single and double quotes for strings.

In order to accomplish the same thing in my Hybrid Android app I do the following

```
String ag = JOString("A" + DBManage.agitation,1);
String po = JOString("P" + (DBManage.preoccupancy + 15),1);
String te = JOString("T"  + DBManage.tensity,1);
```

which returns strings such as `{"P4":2}` etc.  My next step is as follows

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("dow",0);
cv.put("tsn",1);
cv.put("lato",2);
cv.put("agitation",ag);
cv.put("preoccupancy",po);
cv.put("tensity",te);
long rowid = db.insert("moods",null,cv);
```

which works.  However, upon examining the stored values I find that what has gone in is in fact

```
{"dow":0,"tsn":5,"lato":191,"tensity":"{\"T0\":1}","agitation":" 
{\"A1\":1}","preoccupancy":"{\"P15\":1}","taps":"{}"}]
```

Unless I am misunderstanding something here the underlying `ContentValues.put` or the `SQLiteDatabase.insert` implementation has taken it upon itself to escape the quoted strings.  Perhaps this is to be expected given that the benefit of going down the `SQLiteDatabase.insert` route with `ContentValues` is protection from SQL injection attacks.  However, in the present instance it is being a hindrance not a help.

Short of executing raw SQL via `execSQL` is there another way to get the JSON into the SQLite database table here?

---

I should add that simply replacing the double quotes with single quotes

```
String ag = JOString("A" + DBManage.agitation,1);
ag = ag.replaceAll("\"","'");
```

will not work since a subsequent attempt to extract JSON from the table

```
SELECT ifnull((select json_extract(preoccupancy,'$.P4') from moods where dow = '1' AND tsn = '0'),0);
```

would result in the error *malformed JSON* being emitted by the SQLite JSON1 extension.

Comment: the JSON1 extension can only be enabled with build-time option `SQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1` ... most likely not even available on Android. try GSON: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5

Comment: Ummm... not sure how that comment is relevant.  If I was unable to use SQLite JSON1 I would have asked that question.  1. JSON1 is by default available on Androiid, 2. I use the SQLCipher version which most certainly does have it enabled.  I **did not** ask "why does my JSON not work?"

Comment: one can have methods for the data models, alike `.fromJson()` or `.toContentValues()` ...also the Jackson Object Mapper is helpful. `json_extract()` does not always return only the values: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#the_json_extract_function.

Comment: see https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/jackson ...especially "Custom Serializer", "Custom Deserializer" (which might be easier to control than the extract patterns.